# Amazon CloudFront cache invalidation after 'aws s3 sync' CLI to update s3 bucket contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

I have a rails app that uses aws cli to sync bunch of content and config with my s3 bucket like so:

`aws s3 sync --acl 'public-read' #{some_path} s3://#{bucket_path}`

Now I am looking for some easy way to mark everything that was just updated in sync to be marked as invalidated or expired for CloudFront.

I am wondering if there is some way to use `-cache-control` flag that [aws cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) provides to make this happen. So that instead of invalidating CouldFont, just mark the files as expired, so CloudFront will be forced to fetch fresh data from bucket.

I am aware of [CloudFront POST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/CreateInvalidation.html) to mark files for invalidation, but that will mean I will have detect what changed in the last sync, then make the API call. I might have any where from 1000s to 1 file syncing. Not a pleasent prospect.  But if I have to go this route, how would I go about detecting changes without parsing the s3 sync's console output of-course.

Or any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use the `--cache-control` option that aws cli provides to invalidate files in CloudFront. The `--cache-control` option maps directly to the [Cache-Control header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) and CloudFront caches the headers along with the file, so if you change a header you must also invalidate to tell CloudFront to pull in the changed headers.

If you want to use the aws cli, then you must parse the output of the sync command and then use the aws cloudfront cli.

Or, you can use `s3cmd` from s3tools.org. This program provides the the `--cf-invalidate` option to invalidate the uploaded filed in CloudFront and a sync command synchronize a directory tree to S3.

`s3cmd sync --cf-invalidate <local path> s3://<bucket name>`

Read, the [s3cmd usage page](http://s3tools.org/usage) for more details.

Comment: The --cf-invalidate option gives the following error for me:  

ERROR: Parameter problem: Unable to translate S3 URI to CloudFront distribution name: s3://<bucket name>

Comment: I had that error (Unable to translate S3 URI to CloudFront distribution name) when my S3 origin domain name in the CloudFront distribution was set to `bucket_regional_domain_name` (xxxx.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com) instead of `bucket_domain_name` (xxxx.s3.amazonaws.com).

It's a problem in the `s3cmd` code: https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/blob/master/S3/CloudFront.py

Answer (score 5):

What about using the brand new [AWS Lambda](http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)? Basically, it executes custom code whenever an event is triggered in AWS (in your case, a file is synchronized in S3).

Whenever you synchronize a file you get an event similar to:

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "eventVersion": "2.0",
            // ...
            "s3": 
            {
                "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
                // ...
                "object": 
                {
                    "key": "hello.txt",
                    "size": 4,
                    "eTag": "1234"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Thus, you can check the name of the file that has changed and invalidate it in CloudFront. You receive one event for every file that has changed.

I have created a script that invalidates a path in CloudFront whenever an update occurs in S3, which might be a good starting point if you decide to use this approach. It is written in JavaScript (Node.js) as it is the language used by Lambda.

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk'),
    s3 = new aws.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'}),
    cloudfront = new aws.CloudFront();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var filePath = '/' + event.Records[0].s3.object.key,
        invalidateParams = {
            DistributionId: '1234',
            InvalidationBatch: {
                CallerReference: '1',
                Paths: {
                    Quantity: 1,
                    Items: [filePath]
                }
            }
        };

    console.log('Invalidating file ' + filePath);

    cloudfront.createInvalidation(invalidateParams, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);  // an error occurred
        } else {
            console.log(data);  // successful response
        }
    });

    context.done(null,'');
};
```

For more info you can check [Lambda's](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) and [CloudFront's API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html) documentation.

Note however that the service is still in preview and is subject to change.

Comment: That's @admenva... So far this is the best suggestions I have gotten! Lamda looks really interesting. NodeJS is just fine.. I am already using it in the project..I will give it a try and get back..

Answer (score 0):

The AWS CLI tool can [output JSON](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html). Collect the JSON results, then submit an invalidation request per the link you included in your post. To make it really simple you could use a gem like [CloudFront Invalidator](https://github.com/reidiculous/cloudfront-invalidator), which will take a list of paths to invalidate.

Comment: The aws s3 sync CLI doesn't seem to support JSON output. I just tried adding the flag.. nothing in the man page either   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Comment: Ahh, you're right. The option is *supposed* to be global but doesn't seem to work with S3 sync. So you're stuck either parsing the sync output (not so hard, just a regex) or implementing the sync logic yourself.